# Form not in right position

Tags: c#, winforms, topmost, form-control

I'd like to show an instance of a form class for a specific time. The form needs to be topmost and not steal focus. Here is my code:

```
public class mSplashForm : Form
{
    public mSplashForm()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        this.Opacity = 0.92D;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(5, 5);
    }
}


public static void mSplash(int time = 500)
{
    mSplashForm SF = new mSplashForm();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    SF.Width = 500;
    SF.Height = 100;
    SF.Left = 500;
    SF.Top = 500;
    SetWindowPos(SF.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, SF.Left, SF.Top, SF.Width, SF.Height, SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    ShowWindow(SF.Handle, mEnumShowWindowCommands.ShowNoActivate);
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(time);
    SF.Close();
}
```

It works, but the form is not shown in the right position defined using Top and Left parameters. What is wrong please?

Comment: By "not in the right position", where does it end up?  Centered?  In the top left hand corner?

Comment: It starts from top-left corner and with every run it moves a little bit toward bottom-right corner.

Comment: Change the `StartPosition` from `WindowsDefaultLocation` to `Manual`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your form set to start in `FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation`. Add this into your `mSplash` function:

```
SF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

This is why it's trying to position successively down the page (as per your comment) on each opening.

Answer (score 1):

set the start position to manual:

```
this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
SF.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
SF.Width = 500;
SF.Height = 100;
SF.Left = 500;
SF.Top = 500;
```